# Create relationship in Realm .net from response data

Tags: .net, xamarin, realm

I am trying to persist responses from a web service into the local Realm database.

The issue is that there is a relationship between two objects. But since Realm does not support a setter property with ILists types, I am struggling to save the relationship from a Deserialised JSON response.

```
public class Report : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
.....
    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; }
}
```

and then my related object:

```
 public class Contact : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
....
}
```

And during my call to the web service I am trying to persist the response:

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(baseURL + @"Reports");
        var reports= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Report>>(response);
        realm.Write(() =>
        {
            foreach (var report in reports)
            {
                realm.Add(report, update: true);
            }
        });
        return reports;
```

Now, since there is no setter support, the contacts will not be persisted. I am also unable to gather the contacts from the reports in the response to add them separately and persist the relationship manually.

The JSON response looks like the following:

```
{
    "Id": 35558,
    ....,
"contacts": [
  {
    "Id": 125254,
```

Is there a known solution for this or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: How are the Contacts defined in the Json `response`? Are they just key-based? i.e. are they an array of keys?

Comment: Hi SushiHangover, I have added a JSON response example.So the Contacts are embedded in an array in each Report.

Comment: Your json should get persisted fine as RealmObjects, your contacts is a json array, they will be deserialize and "added" to the `IList<Contact>`, when you `Add` the reports to your realm, the contacts are added at the same time. I do this all the time using my json extensions : https://sushihangover.github.io/Realm.Json.Extensions/